# Google DFP is not working with jQuery colorbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, colorbox, google-dfp

DFP ads are not showing when I'm opening the page second time.

Here is what I've:

1. Asp.Net Master Page (**Main.master**) : My site's master where I put the DFP Head tag code.
2. Asp.net page (**Home.aspx**) : My site's home page, which contains the link to open the colorbox pop-up window.
3. Asp.Net page (**About.aspx**): This page will open in colorbox pop-up window.
4. jQuery Colorbox (http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/)

Here is what I'm doing:

1. Open the home page in browser.
2. There is an link (Open Ad Page) to open the pop-up window (colorbox). Click on it. [We are at **MASTER >> HOME** page]
3. It will open the colorbox pop-up window, [We are at **MASTER >> HOME >> About** page],  and DFP ads are loading/showing this time.
4. Close the colorbox pop-up window.
5. Again We are at **MASTER >> HOME** page. Repeat the step 2. I mean click on Open Ad Page. Page will be open but without any ad.

So, please help me to solve this problem.

I'm having very short time to solve this problem.

Please feel free to ask me anything regarding this question.

**Important:**

One more thing I want to share is that on About.aspx page ,in attached sample application, I added the DFP's Div tag twice.

If we add it only single time it doesn't show the image. This is another issue.

Please download TestApp from [HERE](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/group/dfp/attach/ea54170e32dda4c0/DfpTestWeb.zip?part=4&authuser=0).

**Update:**

Colorbox is not re-loading the page completely. I used the FancyBox and it's working fine for me. It is loading the DFP ads on each pop-up window open.

I'm still looking for the solution with colorbox because implement FancyBox is very problematic for me.

Thanks in advance.
Kapil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem my self.

I got very simple answer of this problem.

To open the popup window on **Home.aspx** page I set the **class="ajax"** and it was restricting the page to load second time.

Now I set the **class="iframe"** and it worked for me. Page is loading completely in colorbox popup and DFP ads too. :)